# How to provide adaptive full-width images with CSS background-image — or otherwise?

Tags: html, css, srcset, imageset

My site has full-width hero images. There are currently served as a CSS background-image with a single image URL that is 2000px wide. Loading one or more of these images on a small device is definitely sub-optimal. I would like to serve a 2000px image, a 1440px image, a 992px image, etc to improve page loading time on mobile.

It seems that I can use -webkit-image-set and image-set, but these only take dpi and 1x, 2x, etc. sizes, so that won't help in this case, as I understand it because this won't ever show smaller images on smaller screens. Alternately, I could serve different images with a media query, but that gets complicated fast if you want to serve images based on viewport and if a device is 2x or 3x. Or I could switch to a img tag instead and use srcset, but I have not been able to find a solution to get a full width image that scales both up and down and fills a fixed height. It seems like this should be possible with object-fit: cover, but no combination of max-width, height, max-height, etc that I have tried has worked.

Here's an example of the CSS background-image that I'm trying to make adaptive:

```css
.hero {
display: block;
min-height: 80px;
width: 100%;
float: left;
position: relative;
padding: 0;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-image: url("https://place-hold.it/500x100");
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 500px;"> <!-- for this example, is 100% on our page -->
<a class="hero"></a>
</div>
```

This is on Wordpress with Boostrap.

Comment: Please create an MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Added an MCVE, hope that clarifies. Can this be reopened?

Comment: The V in MCVE is missing from what I can tell.

Comment: I'm not following what you're saying here exactly. What do you think is missing? The snippet verifiably is not showing adaptive images. I'm asking how to add them.

Comment: We expect you add the attempt that you consider closest to what you want to achieve, explain how it fails and how it is supposed to behave differently from what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do that with a picture tag. I like using this tag because i think it gives you more control over the breakpoints.

Look it up here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp

```css
/* Basic styling for body. not important */

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* The parent container needs to have position:relative */

.example-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}


/* The content element needs position:relative, and z-index higher than the BG element */

.example-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0;
}


/* The picture element */

.image-full,
.image-full img {
  display: block;
  
  /* Absolute position the element with full width/height, and a low z-index */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  
  /* Object-fit:cover will make the image fill the space */
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-container">
  <h2 class="example-content">Content goes here</h2>
  <picture class="image-full">
    <source media="(min-width:1200px)" srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1002/4312/2868.jpg?hmac=5LlLE-NY9oMnmIQp7ms6IfdvSUQOzP_O3DPMWmyNxwo">
    <source media="(min-width:500px)" srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667.jpg?hmac=J04WWC_ebchx3WwzbM-Z4_KC_LeLBWr5LZMaAkWkF68">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/100/2500/1656.jpg?hmac=gWyN-7ZB32rkAjMhKXQgdHOIBRHyTSgzuOK6U0vXb1w">
  </picture>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great. Making the container div position:relative was what I was missing.